# Java. Prevent Jar App from multiple running with pop up message "already running". (using ServerSocket())

Tags: java

Currently i am trying to display a pop up message when user trying to run jar more than one time.
My current code is like below

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  new ServerSocket(65535, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());// if there are already one 
                                                         // running jar, it will prevent 
                                                         // the program to execute

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello World \n"); //Display hello world message 
                                                          // when run

}
```

expectation output when user run jar more than one time :

```
Your jar application is already running . . .
```

My question is, how can we display a message tell user the jar application is already running because ServerSocket() will prevent application from running, so "already running "pop up message i put after that will not run.

**ANSWER:**

```
 try{
       new ServerSocket(65535, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello World \n");
    }
 catch(BindException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
             (frame, "Your jar application is already running . . . \n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Your code as written won't actually do that, as you're allowing the ServerSocket to be garbage-collected, which will close it. You need to store it into a variable. You need to catch the BindException, and display your 'already running' popup in there, and then exit. You also need to catch any other IOExceptions that may arise.

Comment: @EJP what type of variable should i store the ServerSocket?

Comment: @EJP +1 it work,Cant believe the solution is so simple. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch `BindException,` and display your 'already running' popup, and then exit, all in that `catch` block.

You also need to catch any other `IOExceptions` that may arise.

You also need to store the `ServerSocket` into a static variable so that it won't be garbage-collected, which will close it.

Answer (score 3):

One commonly used way is to create a File on the disk that says app is running and delete that file on normal termination of jar, check if file exists on startup and display proper message, also consider the case of abnormal termination of jvm

For example eclipse locks current workspace with a `.lock` file

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP -1 isn't supported with your comment :) , why do you think it does not answer the question ?

Comment: Because he specifically says 'using ServerSocket'.

Comment: it still answers the question OP needs minotor around the app not around the socket access

Comment: You've missed the point. The ServerSocket *is* the 'monitor access'. He says so himself. Read the question. You don't need anything else.

Comment: @EJP `_My question is, how can we display a message tell user the jar application is already running because ServerSocket() will prevent application from running, so "already running "pop up message i put after that will not run._` So OP knows the fact that it is going to fail because socket will be alraedy in use and he wants to prevent this case by not allowing user to run another instance of application and my answer answers how to do that

Comment: He wants to *detect* the case and display a popup. Catching BindException already does that, with 100% reliability. Nothing else is required.

Comment: but why would even reach to that state if we can have early catch

Comment: Because you don't *need* an 'early catch', because `catch (BindException ...)` *is* the catch, and it is 100% reliable, unlike lockfile-based solutions. Adding something unreliable just to prevent something reliable from triggering in the same case doesn't begin to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

the best way is that create a file that show status of program and if a program run already, do not let program execute again. but you must be careful; if your program stop unexpected without edit file before terminate it make a lot of problem when you execute your program later

Comment: No, the best way is the way he wants to do it. He didn't ask for another way, and your way isn't as good, as it has several loopholes, as you note yourself, which the listening socket technique doesn't have. -1